# Headless VBox - VRDE not working

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have imported an existing machine on a freshly installed VirtualBox 4.1.6r74727, running on a Ubuntu Server 10.04 box. The guest OS is Windows Server 2003.

Further, I have modified the VM as follows (10.20.30.40 represents the real publc IPv4 address of the host machine):

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "2003" --vrdeaddress 10.20.30.40 --vrde on --vrdeport 3389 --vrdemulticon on --vrdeauthtype external
```

After that, I started the VM with the following:

```
VBoxManage startvm "2003" --type headless --vrde=on
```

When I issue `VBoxManage showvminfo "2003"`, I get the following:

```
VRDE:            enabled (Address 10.20.30.40, Ports 3389, MultiConn: on, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: external)
Video redirection: disabled
```

However, port 3389 stays closed both on 10.20.30.40, and on localhost and I cannot connect to VRDE. What is the reason and how should I approach fixing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doh.. I didn't have the extras pack installed:

```
VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.6-74713.vbox-extpack
```